# Http On Google Container Engine

Tags: docker, cloud, kubernetes

Im stuck on the Google Container Engine. Any tutorial I try out I am never able to connect through a docker container on http.

As a concrete example the wordpress tutorial:
https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-wordpress

I literally follow every step (nothing more, nothing less). Then i try to connect through the browser (chrome) and it says "connection timed out" the ip is returning my pings.

So what step I am missing here? Is the tutorial up to date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your connection is timing out, it sounds like you haven't put the correct firewall rules in place. You can verify this by sshing into your VM and running curl against the wordpress service. If it works using curl but doesn't work from your browser, then the firewall is blocking your requests.

Comment: Checked and curl is working. Browser is not. How to proceed? Like I said, I followed the tutorial word by word.

Comment: If you look at the node VMs in the cloud console, what does it say the tags are? It should be something like gke-clustername-nnnnnnnn-node. That is the tag you should pass to the create firewall rule command. Alternatively, you could try not passing any target tags to the create firewall rule command and see if that helps.

Comment: Checked: gcloud compute firewall-rules create hello-world-80 --allow tcp:80  --target-tags gke-hello-world-0517638b-node-elcz. Checked okay and not working.

Comment: A i think i get it. The postfix -elcz must be omitted. I will retry tomorrow. Big thanks!

Comment: Right, the target tag doesn't include the 4 letter postfix; it only goes through the -node part of the VM name.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback! Works like a charm :)